# What factors make Lake Turkana a great location for preserving fossils?

Tags: paleoclimatology, geomorphology, paleogeography, archaeology

I am trying to figure out why Lake Turkana has yielded so many hominin fossils compared to other locations in the East African Rift Valley. One of the reasons is possibly the laying of sedimentary strata and volcanic activity which creates new layers; this geologically dynamic area is therefore able to preserve fossils. But surely Lake Turkana isn't the only such area, there are other East African rift Lakes such as Tanganyika. What other factors have played into shaping this remarkable fossil rich area?